# MYSQL: diff between tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

- products
- products_tmp

The `products_tmp` table has less fields. But all the fields that are in `products_tmp` are in products.

On import of data I populate the `products_tmp` table and after that I need to do 3 things:

1. check the new products in `products_tmp` that are not in products (get ids) (DONE)
2. check the old products in products that are not in `products_tmp` (get ids for later deletion) (DONE)
3. check for differences on the rest. Both tables have a product-hash unique identifier.

And I need to check differences in fields `title`, `text`, `price`, `photos` and `category_id`. And getting the tmp ids, so I can then update the products table with new values.

Is it possible to do the diff only in mysql?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, I don't quite get you. You already compare the diff (Step 1 & 2), what stop you from doing the third step?

Comment: If, for instance, `products_tmp` contains a price change for one of the products that already exist in `products`, he wants to be able to identify those changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. check the new products in products_tmp that are not in products (get ids) (DONE)

This is straight forward...

```
SELECT pt.*
FROM products_tmp pt
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.product_id = pt.product_id
WHERE p.product_id IS NULL;
```

1. check the old products in products that are not in products_tmp (get ids for later deletion) (DONE)

A always prefer swapping tables to performing `RIGHT JOINS` - personal preference...

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN products_tmp pt ON p.product_id = pt.product_id
WHERE pt.product_id IS NULL;
```

3.check for differences on the rest. Both tables have a product-hash unique identifier.

This one is a little more difficult. Assuming you don't want to do a field-by-field comparison, you could do this...

```
SELECT product_id, count(*) cnt
FROM (
    SELECT p.product_id, p.field2, p.field3
    FROM products p
    UNION
    SELECT pt.product_id, pt.field2, pt.field3
    FROM products_tmp pt
) pd
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING cnt > 1;
```

The `UNION` should naturally join the duplicates together into a single row, so anything with a count of 2 based on your primary key should be a duplicate row. If you put the results of this into a temporary table, you can do more queries to see what the differences are.

Comment: cool, will chek it out... but wouldn't be the problem that products table has 3 more fields than  tmp?

Comment: this is my actual query:

SELECT product_hash, count(*) cnt
FROM (
    SELECT p.product_hash, p.price, p.title
    FROM z_imports_products p
    UNION
    SELECT pt.product_hash, pt.price, pt.title
    FROM z_imports_products_tmp pt
) pd
GROUP BY product_hash
HAVING cnt > 1;`

and I get no results, but I have at least one row with different title!

Comment: scratch that... nvm...made a mistake... it is actually working pretty well!!!

THANKS FOR YOUR TIME and FAST RESPONSE!

Comment: You need to list all of the fields in the two select statements that could contain differences for which you care. If there's a differences in the fields selected, it will show.

Comment: @DougKress How do I now get these differential data and update the 'products' table appropriately?

Comment: @Ethan - I'm not sure if I understand your question - what kind of update would you like to make? If you want to see the differences and not the similarities, you'd simply use "HAVING cnt = 1" instead of "> 1"